# how to callback a method of controller in Angularjs $http.get().success()

Tags: angularjs

I have this code and it is working well:

```
var app = angular.module("resources", []);
    app.service("resourceService", function ($http) {
        return {
            GetAll: function (callBack) {
                $http.get("api/Resource/Get").success(function (data) {
                    callBack(data); 
                })
            }
        }
    });

app.controller("resourcesCtrl", function ($scope, resourceService) {
        $scope.resourceList = [];
        resourceService.GetAll(function (data) { $scope.resourceList = data; });
    });
```

Using "Controller as" syntax in earlier version of angularjs, you can replace `$scope` with `this`. if I do it, my controller will be like:

```
app.controller("resourcesCtrl", function (resourceService) {
    this.resourceList = [];
    this.setResourceList = function(data){
        this.resourceList = data;
    };
    resourceService.GetAll(this.setResourceList);
});
```

I add `setResourceList`, to call it as a method of controller, to have access to the controller context using `this`.
But now, when `setResourceList` method is running as a callback function, the `this` is `window` (as I have a function call, not a method  call), so `this.resourceList` is undefined.
I'm seeking any solution to solve the problem, and I think the problem root is replacing `$scope` with `this`. Is there any way to access the properties of controller when they are not defined using `$scope`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a closure to capture the value of `this`.

```
app.controller("resourcesCtrl", function (resourceService) {
    var that = this;
    this.resourceList = [];
    this.setResourceList = function(data){
        that.resourceList = data;
    };
    resourceService.GetAll(this.setResourceList);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Maurice. Where is the scope of 'that' now?

Comment: Variables in JavaScript are either scoped to a function or global. In this case that is scoped to the controller function and available to each nested function.